# Show JQuery JDialog after 5 seconds and autoclose

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

How to open the JQuery JDialog window if response take more than 5 seconds.

Below is my code

```
$("#Dialog").dialog(
       {
           autoOpen: false,
           modal: true,
           height: 175,
           position: 'center',
           bgiframe: true,
           display: 'visible',
           width: 400
       });
```

I want to show the above dialog if response time (AJAX) takes more than 5 seconds and auto close once i get the response (AJAX).

Any help would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to set a Timer in JS to do it

Comment: You mean response time of an ajax request ?

Comment: @DidierGhys: Yes. Response time of ajax request

Comment: @DidierGhys:  
Can you please help me on how to clearTimeout? Is that an inbuilt function in JQuery?

Comment: @Thameem: DidierGhys provided the clearTimeout() as hyperlink to Mozilla which you can read and the function is provided by DOM.

Comment: @Thameem. clearTimeout is a function of the window object, nothing to do with jQuery. I have linked to documentation for both set/clearTimeout. What is it that you don't understand ? (for comments related to answer, add them to the answer itself please)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to start a timer that will open your dialog after 5 seconds. This method returns a reference to the timer that it creates. Do that in the "beforeSend" callback, which is executed before the request starts.

In the complete callback (or the success + error callback), clear the timer with [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) and close the dialog.

```
var timer;

$.ajax({
    ...
    beforeSend: function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#Dialog").dialog('open');
        }, 5000);
    },
    complete: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#Dialog").dialog('close');
    }
});
```